# Building an Issue Tracker Plugin for TortoiseSVN

Tags: plugins, tortoisesvn, issue-tracking

I've read a lot about IBugTraqProvider interface and implementing an issue tracker into the commit dialog of TortoiseSVN. 
[IBugTraqProvider](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-ibugtraqprovider.html) is written here.

Is there a more simpler way not to do it, building the plug-in and installing it on TortoiseSVN. The Document is not that clear that a developer can create its own plugin.

I'm working with SalesForce as the Issue Tracker, and retrieved the WSDL file to integrate with the Working Items. Now I need to know how to connect it to TortoiseSVN.

Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [issue-tracker-plugins.txt](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse/#svn/trunk/contrib/issue-tracker-plugins) in the contrib directory in the TSVN source code. There's a fairly decent example in C# that should get you heading in the right direction.

When I built a plugin, I built a test harness that passed arbitrary information using the IBugtraqProvider interface, so that I could debug the plugin whilst building it, without having to reinstall the plugin into TSVN each time.